# Using brackets when creating object in vba excel?

Tags: vba

I have copied code from a vba project that I found to go from xml to excel but it gives me an error in my vba project, I have checked the reference libraries.

```
ruta = LCase(CreateObject([explorador]).BrowseForFolder(0, "selecciona la carpeta a procesar", 0, "").items.Item.Path)
```

I made the following change and it worked
ruta = LCase(CreateObject("shell.application").BrowseForFolder(0, "selecciona la carpeta a procesar", 0, "").Items.Item.Path)

but then it came back to this line

With CreateObject([openFile])

I get the error 13 that the execution times do not match. Variables do not match

I check the variables and they are correctly: unsure:

I don't understand why with the original file it runs smoothly and the replica doesn't. It has been very little I have found it with respect to the syntax of those lines of code when writing it [explorer] and [openFile]

Comment: Exactly what are these `explorador` and `openfile` names?

Comment: In VBA the code `[something]` is shorthand for `Evaluate("something")`

So `[A1]` returns `Range("A1")`, and `[1+2]` is `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets in VBA are used for what the language specification calls "foreign identifiers"; they're how you can explicitly invoke a `Range` object's default member, which is a hidden member named `_Default` - since VBA identifiers cannot begin with an underscore, doing `MsgBox SomeRange._Default` would be illegal. So we do `MsgBox SomeRange.[_Default]` instead and now the code can compile and run. Same with the `SomeCollection.[_NewEnum]` hidden member, when creating custom collection classes.

When the bracketed identifier doesn't contain any illegal-in-an-identifier characters, then they are purely redundant.

Various VBA hosts also implement some form of `Evaluate` mechanism; when hosted in Excel, you can do this `MsgBox [A1]` and you'll get the value of cell A1 from the active worksheet - in this context `[A1]` is an expression VBA takes and passes to the host application (here Excel), which evaluates it and returns a result to VBA - in this case a `Range` object reference.

So what `CreateObject([explorador])` really does, is really this:

```
CreateObject(ActiveSheet.Range("explorador").Value)
```

Except Excel doesn't understand what `explorador` is referring to (is the sheet supposed to define a `explorador` named range? I can't imagine why you'd want to do that though), and comes back with what would show up as a `#NAME?` error on a worksheet, wrapped up in a `Variant/Error` value:

```
CreateObject(CVErr(XlErrName)) 'type mismatch error every time!
```

Lose the square brackets, you'll lose the headache with them!

Assuming `explorador` and `openfile` are `String` variables containing a valid/registered ProgID, `CreateObject(explorador)` should work as intended.

Consider using either string literals or declared constants with `CreateObject`: having a layer of indirection here is obscuring exactly what type of COM object is being created. `With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` can only fail if the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` isn't in the registry.

Comment: I have already reviewed how I can explain you better so that you can give me some help